# localhost cannot be run

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost

A couple months ago I made a one web application, and everything was great until couple hours ago when I want to run same application on localhost but I get some screen which I dont understand. XAMP work fine
And also phpmyadmin cannot be run as well. 
Please help, everything I tried i can not find a solution

[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTSAA.jpg)

[Phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuvND.jpg)

Comment: Can you check what port of localhost you are using in XAMP? e.g. `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Do you have the Apache and MySQL services started? Having XAMP running isn't enough by default. It should look something like this: http://imgur.com/SLmBvx5

Comment: Yeah, everything working. XAMP is on, Apache and MySQL working fine 
http://imgur.com/a/5Yhkz